# Как сделать электронную библиотеку книг на MySQL и PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток господа.

Я пытаюсь реализовать электронную библиотеку книг:
В MySQL добавить данные автора и название книги ( с этим вроде разобрался, добавил author и title через команду SQL);
Как-то соединить эти ячейки с файлом книги;
Через PHP сделать поиск по базе данных с выводом подходящих книг и последующей возможностью их скачивания.

Как сделать так, чтобы перед поиском, человек смог ввести автора или название книги и далее уже бы происходил поиск и вывод подходящих вариантов, с последующей возможность скачивания?

Я начинаю учить PHP и MySQL и по этому прошу помощи у вас, профессионалов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Иван, не в обиду будет сказано, но начали бы вы с онлайн курсов для новичков. Например тут https://www.codecademy.com/ru/learn/php

Comment: дополнительно посмотрите готовые разработки (типа http://www.dub-project.ru/),  также CMS  заточиные под библиотеки. Если Вы только начинаете изучать, то чтобы самому с нуля это реализовать будет нужно очень много времени... а настроить уже готовое решение значительно проще....

Answer (score 1):

Для начала скажу, что у вас в вопросе не одна, а целый набор задач, которые требуются решить.

**База данных**

Для начала вам надо спроектировать хранилище, в котором будет содержаться информация о вашей библиотеке. Необходимо сделать таблицы, которые будут хранить информацию о книгах и различные служебные данные.

**WEB Приложение**

Надо будет написать полноценное web-приложение, которое будет как минимум выдавать пользователю страницу поиска, делать запросы в базу данных и выдавать результаты.

**Файловый сервер**

Как понимаю, у вас будет не только возможность поиска информации о книгах, но и возможность скачать их в различных форматах? Тогда потребуется файловое хранилище в рамках вашего хостинга или отдельный сервер. На нем вы будете хранить файлы книг, а в базе данных будут храниться только ссылки на эти файлы.

P.S. Как вариант, можно в начале использовать какое-нибудь готовое решение, чтобы  не тратить много времени на написание кода с нуля. Смотрите GitHub там есть открытый качественный код для вашей задачи.

Comment: У меня книги будут храниться в корневой папке сайта в одном формате PDF и мне нужно указать в базе что определенный автор или определённое название книги относятся к этому файлу и при отображении результата, просто выводились 3 информации, автор, название и кликабельная сылка, очень прошу помочь или хотябы скинуть то где можно об этом почитать)

Comment: чтобы соотнести файл книги к мета-информации о ней, просто храните путь к этому файлу в базе данных и в этой же строке указывайте автора, название и прочую информацию.